# Add Array Value from Array1 if Key Matches in Array2 (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, merge, match

I'm trying to merge two arrays when there is a key match.

"mac" array should match "id[0]" key, and if match is true append "id[1]" value to my "ip".

For this example will use "computer", "ip address" and "mac address"

```
id = {
  '01:02:03:04:05:06' => 'Desktop'
  '07:08:09:10:11:12' => 'Laptop'
}

ip = { '192.168.0.10', '192.168.0.20' }
mac = { '01:02:03:04:05:06', '07:08:09:10:11:12' }
```

Code I'm using so far;

```
net = ip.zip(mac)
net.each do |ip,mac|
  puts "#{ip} / #{mac}"
end
```

Example output (wanted):

```
192.168.0.10 / 01:02:03:04:05:06 / Desktop
192.168.0.20 / 07:08:09:10:11:12 / Laptop
```

Comment: Tux, a few observations: 1. `ip` and `mac` are arrays, so enclose with `[]`, not `{}` (plz edit); 2. it is confusing to give the (local-to-) block variables the same names as the arrays `ip` and `mac`; 3. you could chain to avoid the need for the temporary variable `net` (i.e., `ip.zip(mac).each {|i,m| puts ... }`); 4. elements of a hash cannot be identified with indices (`id[0]` is the value corresponding to key `0`, or `nil` if there is no key `0`), so instead say something like, "for a given element `m` of `mac`, if `id` contains an element with key `m`, then append `id[m]` to...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `id` (rename it to `hostnames`) is a Hash and not an Array, thus you can look up on the fly and change the line with `puts` to:

```
puts "#{ip} / #{mac} / #{id[mac]}"
```

Not sure if that matches your question and requirements. If so, please change the question title (hash lookup).

Comment: I'll rename it to "host" but your example worked :-) Thank you!

Comment: I was momentarily confused until it clicked that you were replacing just one line of the questioner's code.   Depending what "if there is a match" means, maybe `puts "#{ip}" + (id[mac] ? " / #{mac} / #{id[mac]}" : "")`.